# DirectoryInfo.Exists Returns false with UNC path

Tags: vb.net, dns, directory, tablet, unc

Well, I have an application which is on a non-domain tablet.

On start the application shells commands the proper creds to a network unc path

```
Shell("net use \\mypath\destloca password username")
```

this command is correct and does what it is suppose to.

Next, I call

```
 Dim dir As New IO.DirectoryInfo(loca)

 If Not dir.Exists Then
        MessageBox.Show("There are no records for loca", "Alert", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, MessageBoxOptions.ServiceNotification)
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

This usually works fine however every once in a while it will return false. The network is connected but i am not able to get to domain resources.

However, after I Shell again I am able to access the UNC path.

Anybody got any ideas?

Comment: It sounds like the `net use` command fails periodically.

Comment: thanks for the response.... I think it came down to the network being dropped by a router...... I just did redundant call to net use if it fails...